# framebox does not work for lstlisting environment

Tags: listings, framed

I am looking a way to wrap something with a frame. I try different approaches but finally choose to use `fancybox` package and `minipage` (because I need to control the width of the frame). It works pretty good for text-only content

```
\usepackage{fancybox}

\begin{document}
  \fbox{%
    \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
      \textbf{Why we use negative angle in above calculate?}\newline
       Since .... we have to ....
    \end{minipage}
  }
\end{document}
```

However, if we add any environment like `lstlisting` or `verbatim`, it doesn't work

```
  \fbox{%
    \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
      \textbf{Why we use negative angle in above calculate?}\newline
       Since .... we have to ....
       \begin{lstlisting}
          A = x+y;
          B = x^2-2y;
       \end{lstlisting}
    \end{minipage}
  }
```

Is that any way to make it work?

p.s. I have created a webpage for the user to type the latex stuff inside and whatever they type, I will like to wrap that with a framebox and generated a pdf with pdflatex. I cannot control what they type, they might type text, math, environment and/or mix all of those. So any better way to frame whatever the latex stuff inside?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because `listings` (including `verbatim` content) cannot be passed as arguments to other functions/macros (without care). Boxing the content first is okay though:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}% http://ctan.org/pkg/listings
\newsavebox{\codebox}% For saving code
\begin{document}
\begin{lrbox}{\codebox}
\begin{lstlisting}
A = x+y;
B = x^2-2y;
\end{lstlisting}
\end{lrbox}

\noindent
\fbox{%
  \begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}
    \textbf{Why we use negative angle in above calculate?}\newline
      Since .... we have to .... \par
    \usebox{\codebox}
  \end{minipage}%
}
\end{document}
```

`lrbox` is an environment that takes one mandatory (box) argument which it will use to store the content in. I've made on called `\codebox`. Do this *outside* your `\fbox` and then use `\usebox{\codebox}` *inside* `\fbox`'s argument.

Note the use of `\noindent`, occational `%` (see [What is the use of percent signs (`%`) at the end of lines?](http://goo.gl/awJkj)) and a `\dimexpr` for the `minipage` size to avoid overfull `\hbox` warnings.

---

If you don't have control over what the user inserts and they could mix/match content, then you might be better off boxing *everything* and just `\fbox`-ing the output:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}% http://ctan.org/pkg/listings
\newsavebox{\userinput}% For saving user input
\begin{document}
\begin{lrbox}{\userinput}
\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}
  \textbf{Why we use negative angle in above calculate?}\newline
   Since .... we have to ....

\begin{lstlisting}
A = x+y;
B = x^2-2y;
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}
\end{lrbox}

\noindent
\fbox{\usebox{\userinput}}%
\end{document}
```

Of course, [`mdframed`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mdframed) has no problem with this kind of thing, and might be a better option; it also allows for frame breaking across the page boundary:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings,mdframed}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{listings,mdframed}
\begin{document}
\begin{mdframed}
  \textbf{Why we use negative angle in above calculate?}\newline
   Since .... we have to ....

\begin{lstlisting}
A = x+y;
B = x^2-2y;
\end{lstlisting}
\end{mdframed}

\end{document}
```

See the [`mdframed` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/mdframed/mdframed.pdf) for more details on making things fancy.

Comment: Hi Werner, thanks for the reply. I am wondering if this is the only way to make it work by using lrbox and with other stuffs like \par. I have a python script to generate the frame box, so whatever the user type, I just want to wrap it with a frame. But I cannot control what the user type, he may use listing or not or mix listing and other command. So any way to wrap whatever latex command, text, math and/or environments people typed? Thanks

Comment: @user1285419: I've added two alternatives.

Answer (score 3):

The [`listings`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/listings) package provides in-built options for framing `listings` environments, either globally using (for example)

```
\lstset{frame=single}
```

or else locally using (for example)

```
\begin{lstlisting}[frame=single]
```

A complete MWE follows

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{frame=single}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[frame=single]
          A = x+y;
          B = x^2-2y;
       \end{lstlisting}

\begin{lstlisting}[backgroundcolor=\color{yellow!20}]
          A = x+y;
          B = x^2-2y;
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use and enviorment that accepted Verbatim content like **adjustbox**

```
\usepackage{adjustbox}
...

\begin{adjustbox}{minipage=[t][0.5\textheight]{1\textwidth},fbox}
  ...
  \begin{lstlisting}[language=..., ...]
    your code
  \end{lstlisting}
  ...
\end{adjustbox}
```

or you can leave void *textheight* for the auto height

```
\begin{adjustbox}{minipage=[t][]{1\textwidth},fbox}
```

Comment: While this might answer (the very old question ;-)) it's preferred to post complete examples